# How to configure fail2ban email destination globally

Tags: fail2ban

I'd like fail2ban to send me alert emails for any events. There seem to be dest variables littered throughout the config files in `/etc/fail2ban` and `/etc/fail2ban/action.d`

Is there a way to set one destination email for all events? I can't seem to find up to date documentation on this.

jail.local contains:

```
# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
```

But where is `destemail` set? It would also be useful to know how to quickly test that the `destemail` is working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` (on centos 6.7) which has been copied from `jail.conf`.

A one liner to test that mail deilvery is working would be

```
echo "My message" | mail -s subject your@email.co.uk
```